# Very loud static and buzzing noise, Behringer UM2 Audio Interface + AT2020. Microphone not working

Tags: microphone, noise, audio-interfaces, broken

I don't have much knowledge about this subject so bare with me.

I have a AT-2020 Microphone and a Behringer UM2 Audio Interface. I have direct monitor enabled and plug in my headphones to the audio interface.

I got on this morning and there was a constant buzzing/crackling noise, but it doesn't sound like a grounding issue, as I have had those before and was able to fix them, this does sound different. The noise is constant and my microphone does not come through at all. The noise happens even when my microphone is unplugged. When the XLR cable is completely unplugged from both devices, the noise is still very loud but it does sound different.

I'm thinking I just need to replace the interface with something better because I haven't heard great things about Behringer while researching a fix for this.

Here is a recording of the noise if that helps. https://vocaroo.com/btos1OpP55T

I'm out of options at this point but I don't want to buy a new interface if I do not have to

Comment: Did you try other methods of troubleshooting? Changing the usb cable, seeing what records if direct monitoring is off, did it used to work fine or has it been like this out of the box?

Comment: +48v is for phantom power. Usually for powering certain microphones. For line level input such as guitar, keys, bass, it should be off.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues with my setup (The exact same as yours) and I think it's got to do with the type of USB port it is in. I would stay away from USB 3.0 ports. I unplugged only the USB connection to the computer and switched it to a USB 2.0 port and it went back to not making the noise anymore. Another thing to consider is to turn off the +48v switch on the back of the device when unplugging or plugging in the device. I don't know the science behind it all but maybe that has something to do with the interference as well. I ruled out the Microphone, mic cable, and the Behringer as being the issue because when listening to the direct monitoring the mic sounded fine. So just to be safe, turn off the +48v, unplug only the USB from the computer, switch ports, turn on the +48v and see where that gets you. Best of luck!

Comment: The USB port part worked flawlessly for me, thanks!